# Changing the fractions in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have fractions as string in my database and it is currently like this:

```
3/8
```

I want to change to this:

```
<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>
```

I have many fractions like this. How do I change them at one shot in SQL? I know I need to use Regular Expressions but not sure how to use it.

What I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE question_table 
SET `option` = Replace(`option`, ?? ,??)
WHERE `option` LIKE  '%/%'
```

Not sure what to fill up in ??.

Comment: MySQL does not have a regex replace function. Either use a UDF (https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg); or dump the mysql data to a file and update there; or use mariadb.

Comment: Do you have fractions like `3/8` only?

Comment: 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 and many more like these

Comment: Replace will work fine here

Comment: A database stores information.  The rendering should be left to the display mechanism (PHP / HTML / etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM strings;
+--------+
| string |
+--------+
| 19/32  |
| 3/8    |
| 5/16   |
+--------+

SELECT *
     , CONCAT('<sup>'
             , SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,'/',1)
             , '</sup>&frasl;<sub>'
             , SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,'/',-1)
             ,'</sub>'
             ) x 
          FROM strings;

+--------+-----------------------------------+
| string | x                                 |
+--------+-----------------------------------+
| 19/32  | <sup>19</sup>&frasl;<sub>32</sub> |
| 3/8    | <sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>   |
| 5/16   | <sup>5</sup>&frasl;<sub>16</sub>  |
+--------+-----------------------------------+

UPDATE strings 
  SET string = CONCAT('<sup>'
                   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,'/',1)
                   , '</sup>&frasl;<sub>'
                   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,'/',-1)
                   , '</sub>'
                   );

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM strings;
+-----------------------------------+
| string                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| <sup>19</sup>&frasl;<sub>32</sub> |
| <sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>   |
| <sup>5</sup>&frasl;<sub>16</sub>  |
+-----------------------------------+
```